# align content horizontal without going to new row

Tags: css

I want to align content in same row, tried using display: inline, span but i ran out of ideas, I want basically checkbox remember me be in same line as Register. Adding code and jsfiddle bellow:

```
    <body>

  <header>
        <div class="container">


 <form class="login-form">
<input type="text" placeholder="Email Adress">
<input type="password" placeholder="Password">

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="remember">Remember me
<div class="login-options">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#">Register</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</form>

        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="container">

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div></div></div>

    </header> <!--end of header-->  
  </body>
```

css

```
    body {
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
    font-size: 12px;
} 

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}

li{
     list-style-type: none;
}

h1, 
h2, 
h3, 
h4, 
h5, 
h6 {
    color: #4f4f4f;
    font-family: "BebasNeue", sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
}

header{
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-top: 30px;
  height: 200px;
}

header .login-form{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 300px;
    color: black;
}

.login-form input[type="text"]{
    height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #ffe6e6;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #FFF;
}

.login-form input[type="text"]:focus{
    border: 2px solid #ffe6e6;
}

.login-form input[type="password"]{
    height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #ffe6e6;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.login-form input[type="password"]:focus{
    border: 2px solid #ffe6e6;
}

.login-form .login-options{
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 230px;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3m7wnq4b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```css
body {
 background-color: #E3E3E3;
 font-size: 12px;
} 

a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFF;
}

li{
  list-style-type: none;
}

h1, 
h2, 
h3, 
h4, 
h5, 
h6 {
    color: #4f4f4f;
    font-family: "BebasNeue", sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
}

header{
 background-color: #2C2C2C;
 color: #FFF;
 padding-top: 30px;
  height: 200px;
}

header .login-form{
 position: absolute;
 top: 30px;
 right: 300px;
 color: black;
}

.login-form input[type="text"]{
 height: 30px;
 border: 2px solid #ffe6e6;
 border-radius: 3px;
 color: #FFF;
}

.login-form input[type="text"]:focus{
 border: 2px solid #ffe6e6;
}

.login-form input[type="password"]{
 height: 30px;
 border: 2px solid #ffe6e6;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

.login-form input[type="password"]:focus{
 border: 2px solid #ffe6e6;
}

.login-form .login-options{
 position: relative;
 bottom: 27px;
    left: 230px;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
 <body>

  <header>
  <div class="container">
  
   
 <form class="login-form">
<input type="text" placeholder="Email Adress">
<input type="password" placeholder="Password">

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="remember">Remember me
<div class="login-options">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#">Register</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</form>

  <div class="navbar">
   <div class="container">

    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div></div></div>
  
 </header> <!--end of header-->  
  </body>
```

Comment: yes right...because u already set position relative..to it..welcome